# C# collecting points in separate lists for every player in game

Tags: c#, list

I am making a game where you first choose how many players there are, then you throw 3 darts each which gives you a random score between 0-20 and you continue until one player gets over 301 points. The score that the player gets is put in a list and that's how the program sees if it's more than 301 points. My problem is that right now the list that is supposed to collect the players points instead collects the points from all the players combined so the program stops after all the players reach 301 points combined. I want the program to know which player it is and put all the players scores in separate lists so that it can know if a player reached 301 points. I'm relatively new to C# so sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace dart
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game My_game = new Game();
            My_game.PlayGame();
        }
    }

    public class Game
    {
        private List<Player> player_list = new List<Player>();
        private List<int> total_list = new List<int>();

        public void PlayGame()
        {

            Random random_number = new Random();
            int throw1;
            int throw2;
            int throw3;

            string more_players = "yes";

            while (more_players == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is the players name?: ");
                player_list.Add(new Player(Console.ReadLine()));
                Console.WriteLine("Are there more players?");
                more_players = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n Welcome to the dartgame! \n" +
                          "\n Game Rules: Each player throws 3 darts at a time." +
                          "\n Every throw can be worth 0-20 points." +
                          "\n Whoever gets 301 points first is the winner!");

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlayers:");

            foreach (var players in player_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(players);
            }

            int total_points = 0;

            while (total_points <= 301)
            {
                foreach (var players in player_list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n first throw for{0}!", players);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press space to throw a dart!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    throw1 = random_number.Next(1, 20);
                    Console.WriteLine("You got " + throw1 + " points!");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n second throw for{0}!", players);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press space to throw a dart!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    throw2 = random_number.Next(1, 20);
                    Console.WriteLine("You got " + throw2 + " points!");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n third throw for{0}!", players);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press space to throw a dart!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    throw3 = random_number.Next(1, 20);
                    Console.WriteLine("You got " + throw3 + " points!");
                    total_points = throw1 + throw2 + throw3;
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPoints for this round: " + total_points);
                    total_list.Add(total_points);
                    total_points = total_list.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
                    players.Add_turn(throw1, throw2, throw3);
                }

                foreach (var players in player_list)
                {
                    players.print_turns();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        private string name;
        private List<Turns> turn_list = new List<Turns>();
        public Player(string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
        }

        public void Add_turn(int turn1, int turn2, int turn3)
        {
            turn_list.Add(new Turns(turn1, turn2, turn3));
        }

        public int calculate_points()
        {
            int total = 0;
            foreach (var turns in turn_list)
            {
                total = total + turns.Get_Score();
            }
            return total;
        }

        public void print_turns()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Points for {0}", name);
            foreach (var turns in turn_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(turns);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n Total points: {0}", calculate_points());
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format(" {0} ", name);
        }
    }

    class Turns
    {
        private int turn1;
        private int turn2;
        private int turn3;

        public Turns(int _turn1, int _turn2, int _turn3)
        {
            turn1 = _turn1;
            turn2 = _turn2;
            turn3 = _turn3;
        }

        public int Get_Score()
        {
            int totalt;
            totalt = turn1 + turn2 + turn3;
            return totalt;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("\n throw 1: {0} \n throw 2: {1} \n throw 3: {2}", turn1, turn2, turn3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest change is `while (total_points <= 301)` to `while (!player_list.Any(x=> x.calculate_points() >= 301)` but not as performant, better to keep running total than calculate each time

Comment: `> 301` that is, since game over when goes above, see @Ashkan answer below for a better refactor of running total however

Answer (score 3):

You can have a player class like this:

```
class Player
{
      public int Points {get; set;}
      //...some other properties
}
```

Now `Payers` can be `List<Player>`:

```
List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();
```

that you can add your players.
then you would add each players point to only that player like:

```
var player = Players[i];
Player.Point += YourRandomPoint;
```

the Sum of points would be `Players.Sum(p=> p.Points)`

so if you want to see all players together has reached 301 points you can have your loop like:

```
while(Players.Sum(p=> p.Points<301))
{
    // continue the game
}
```

or if you want to see if there is a player with 301+ points as @ MistyK suggests in comments then you can do your loop like:

```
while(!Players.Any(p=> p.Points>=301))
{
    // continue the game
}
```

Comment: any player has 301 means you should check if there is a player with more than 301 points rather than sum of them is bigger than 301, right?

Comment: @MistyK I might have misunderstood the OP. I added what you suggested to the code too. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: You haven't played darts, have you ?:p

Comment: Well as you see, I haven't. I corrected my answer as you see. Thanks to you

Comment: Well, this game isn't the true 301 dart game, you usually start from 301 and go to zero, and usually have to start and end on a double ;)

Comment: `Players.Sum(p => p.Points<301)` would not even compile, I think you put the closing parenthesis in the wrong place..